# How to allow Ultimate Member non-admin users to submit my custom plugin form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am developing my first Wordpress plugin that has a front-end form for the registered Members but I'm getting redirected to the homepage similar to this [phantom 302 redirect problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14854/phantom-302-status-code-when-sending-a-post-requests-on-pages). However *if I submit the same form using an admin account, it goes through and gets inserted to the database*, so I figured the problem is with the Member accounts. I am using [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) plugin for user registration.

I've done the accepted solution on that particular problem to no avail.

Here's an example of my **HTML form**, you can see I prefixed the name of the fields to ensure uniqueness:

```
<form action="http://localhost/mysite/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post" class="delivery-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="schedule_delivery">
    <h3>Recipient's Information</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="r_first_name">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="r_first_name" id="r_first_name" placeholder="First Name" required value="Example">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="r_last_name">Last Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="r_last_name" id="r_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required value="Example">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="r_address">Street Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="r_address" id="r_address" placeholder="Street Address" required value="Example">
    </div>

    ...

    <h3>Package Information</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="weight">Weight (kg)<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="pkg_weight" id="weight" required>
    </div>

    ...

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cost">Cost</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="0" name="pkg_cost" id="cost" readonly>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's the **database object declaration** and adding the insert function to the hook:

```
if( class_exists( 'DBClass' ) ) {

        $db = DBClass::getInstance();

}

add_action( 'admin_post_schedule_delivery', array( $db , 'insert_schedule_request' ) );
```

I've also tried *'admin_post_nopriv'* but both Admin and Member could not submit.

Lastly, the **insert function**:

```
function insert_schedule_request() {

    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->insert( $this->get_table_name(), array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
        'schedule_date' => current_time('mysql'),
        'r_first_name' => $_POST['r_first_name'],
        'r_last_name' => $_POST['r_last_name'],
        'r_address' => $_POST['r_address'],
        ...
        'pkg_weight' => $_POST['pkg_weight'],
        ...
        'pkg_cost' => $_POST['pkg_cost']
    ), array(
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        ...
        '%f',
        ...
        '%f'
    ));

    wp_redirect( home_url( 'success-page' ) );

}
```

I tried looking for a solution all day but I just ran out of queries to search. Appreciate all the help. TIA.